# The difference between View and ScrollView in styling

Tags: ios, react-native, view, scrollview, react-native-stylesheet

This is my component code and my style code:

```js
function StartGameScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.numberInput}
        maxLength={2}
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
      <PrimaryButton>Reset</PrimaryButton>
      <PrimaryButton>Confirm</PrimaryButton>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff6868",
    marginTop: 100,
    padding: 16,
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
  },
  numberInput: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    fontSize: 32,
    borderBottomColor: "yellow",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    color: "yellow",
    marginVertical: 8,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

And this picture is a result when I rendered:

[image: rendered image with just 'View' component]

But when I change `View` to `ScrollView`, it rendered to this (`View` component to `ScrollView`):

[image]

I'm curious that I used the same style elements but I got different result.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your `ScrollView` inside `SafeAreaView` will fix this issue for you.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.numberInput}
          maxLength={2}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <PrimaryButton>Reset</PrimaryButton>
        <PrimaryButton>Confirm</PrimaryButton>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

It's happening because your `ScrollView` will take whatever height is available to it and by default it is `100%`.

Another, solution could be to wrap your container `View` inside of a `ScrollView`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.numberInput}
          maxLength={2}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <PrimaryButton>Reset</PrimaryButton>
        <PrimaryButton>Confirm</PrimaryButton>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your case, the unexpected layout that occurs after switching to ScrollView may be caused by the marginTop: 100 in the inputContainer style. If the content is not tall enough to fit the given area, the marginTop may push the content down, leaving empty space at the top.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView`'s style by default contains `flexGrow:1` which will distribute the free space in the container that makes the view to fill up all the spaces.

In the `ScrollView` adding `flexGrow:0` in the `inputContainer` style to have a similar result as `View`